# Why is hyperlinking extending to text after anchor element?

Tags: html

I am working on a navigation bar for a basic website. I must be overlooking something simple but when I try to add text below the nav bar, it still is carrying over the link tag. No matter what I write, it still extends the previous link. Does anyone know what I'm overlooking that's obvious?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav id="navigation" class="clearfix">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html" title="Home Page">Home Page<br/>
   <li><a href="information.html" title="General Information">General Information<br/>
   <li><a href="keynote.html" title="Speakers">Keynote Speakers<br/>
   <li><a href="call.html" title="Call for Papers">Call for Papers<br/>
   <li><a href="dates.html" title="Important Dates">Important Dates<br/>
   <li><a href="major.html" title="Major Areas">Major Areas<br/>
   <li><a href="paper.html" title="Submit a Paper">Paper Submission<br/>
   <li><a href="reviewer.html" title="Login">Reviewer Login<br/>
   <li><a href="register.html" title="Register online">Online Registration<br/>
   <li><a href="conference.html" title="Conference">Conference Program<br/>
   <li><a href="guidelines.html" title="Guidelines">Guidelines<br/>
   <li><a href="comments.html" title="Comments and Feedback">Comments and Feedback<br/>
  </ul>
</nav>

why is this linking back to the comments page? I want to start adding text.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even though HTML5 allows you to leave tags unclosed, it is considered a **bad habit**. Sometimes a browser will not know when and where to close an open tag, especially with multiple levels of nesting.

Comment: On possible approach instead of "No matter what I write" is to run HTML validator on your HTML, like http://validator.w3.org/ - i.e. you sample generates at least 50 errors... (including lack of closing tags for `li` and `a`).

Comment: The `li` elements do not need closing tags, but the `a` elements do (always). The only problem I see here with unclosed elements is with the `a` elements. The end tag for `li` can pretty much always be omitted safely.

Comment: Citation regarding the fact that the `li` tag can be omitted: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-li-element which reads, *An li element's end tag can be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your html tags `<li>` and `<a>`. Example: `<li><a href="#">Your link</a></li>`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something obvious

Comment: @Vortex11 http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Actually, the end tags for the `li` element can almost always be safely omitted. The only problem with unclosed elements that I can see here are with the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your elements.

Each `<li>` and `<a>` should end with  `</a>` and `</li>`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/adfqbsws/1/

The `<a>` element [requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) a closing `</a>` tag. The omission of the `</a>` in your code is the source of your problem.

The `<li>` element [does not always require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) a closing `</li>` tag, but I would recommend  always using it as a best practice.

No need for the `<br>` tags in this case.

Comment: @Vortex11 http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The `li` elements in this document definitely do not require closing tags.  The `a` element on the other hand does always require a closing tag. That’s the only unclosed-element problem here, not the lack of `li` closing tags.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, you are correct. An `<li>` doesn't require a closing tag if it is followed by another `<li>` or there is no subsequent content in the parent element. I wrote that in my answer based on habit and what I consider best practices, not what's in the spec. I'll revise my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael_B Yeah, it think it arguably is best practice to include it. But that’s also a subjective thing that others may reasonably disagree with. Anyway, you are of course right on the essential point here the if somebody omits end tags for the **`a` elements**, they’re gonna have a bad time…

Comment: Also kudos for taking time to point out that the `<br>` tags are needed in the OP’s document. No idea what the intent of those is there o_O